# Spring Boot and Logback: Disable a logger

Tags: logging, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot 1.4 together with Logback, I configure the logging in the `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: INFO
    com.netflix.eureka: OFF
```

Note that the recommendation for the second configuration comes straight from the [Spring Cloud Service Registration and Discovery](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/) documentation. It works quite well for INFO and other ‘normal’ levels. However, the log also shows (reformatted by me):

```
… o.s.cloud.logging.LoggingRebinder        : Cannot set level: false for
        'org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener'
```

Now, `false` is a very interesting level, isn’t it? How can I disable a logger completely?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The yaml-parser interprets the words `OFF` and `ON` as `Boolean` and so passes `false` or `true` to the logging framework.
If you want to disable logging with the level `OFF` you need to set the value of the property as a `String` which can be achieved by single quotes.
Your example modified:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: INFO
    com.netflix.eureka: 'OFF'
```

Comment: That’s it. It seems I simply didn’t wonder enough about that `false` in the error message.