# How to disable excessive Logging [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

While running my spring application i am getting lots of DEBUG log in my console tried most of the suggestions for this but none of it working, the dependency of my pom.xml is attached below.
In this project using Spring, hibernate.

Thanks.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>

            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>

            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>

            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
                <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469739/spring-boot-and-logback-disable-a-logger/39470568

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya i have tried not working

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after including Liquibase in my project. Had to explicitly set [logging provider for JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging) inside `project.yml`:

```
org:
  jboss:
    logging:
      provider: jdk
```